# Create new array based on the value and shapes of current array

Tags: python, arrays, vectorization

Suppose I have an array contains index [2,1,1,2,0], I would like to create a new array 3x5 that only has value equal to 1 at index 2 for first row, at index 1 for second row, and so on..
For example:

```
[[0, 0, 1], #2
 [0, 1, 0], #1
 [0, 1, 0], #1
 [0, 0, 1], #2
 [1, 0, 0]] #0
```

How could I vectorize this procedure without using for loop?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this as a single operation directly in python. That isnt even valid python syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

in_index =  [2,1,1,2,0]
len_in_index = len(in_index)
result = np.zeros((len_in_index, 3), dtype=int)
for i in range(len_in_index):
    result[i, in_index[i]] = 1
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to do it without a for loop?